# How can I omit NA coefficients from the lm summary output?

Tags: r, lm

I have a regression with many qualitative interactions and some of the combinations don't have any observations. How do I exclude the interaction coefficients with no observations from the `summary.lm()` output?

Comment: Please read: [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be hard (impossible?) to do without hacking the `summary.lm()` method, but if you are willing to look just at the coefficient table you can just use `na.omit(coef(summary(...))))`.

Example:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100))
## add redundant variables
d$x2 <- d$x3 <- d$x1
m1 <- lm(y~.,data=d)  ## fit y to all other vars

summary(m1)
na.omit(coef(summary(m1)))
##               Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept) -0.0329789 0.09341769 -0.3530263 0.724827
## x1           0.1002849 0.09341569  1.0735337 0.285668
```